# Очищение данных в цикле

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Господа подскажите как быть ... 
Есть Класс, тут все понятно вроде, подключится к стрингам , взять инфу из WMI передать в return

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

namespace test {
  public class MB {

    private ManagementObjectSearcher DiskDriveSearcher;

    public MB(string stringi) {
      DiskDriveSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + stringi + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    }

    public IEnumerable < string > Disk_Name {
      get {

        foreach(ManagementObject querObj in DiskDriveSearcher.Get()) {

          yield
          return querObj["Caption"].ToString() + ", " + (ulong.Parse(querObj["Size"].ToString()) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)).ToString() + "Gb";

        }

      }

    }

    public IEnumerable < string > Disk_Values {
      get {

        foreach(ManagementObject querObj in DiskDriveSearcher.Get()) {

          yield
          return (ulong.Parse(querObj["Size"].ToString()) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)).ToString() + "Gb";

        }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Далее у меня, идет построение дерева.

```js
public HardWare(string ws) {

  MB mi = new MB(ws);
  TreeViewItem ceo = new TreeViewItem() {
    Header = "Инвентаризация"
  };
  TreeViewItem Disk = new TreeViewItem() {
    Header = "Диск"
  };

  //диск
  foreach(string disk_ in mi.Disk_Name) {


    TreeViewItem Hdd_va = new TreeViewItem() {
      Header = "HDD: " + disk_
    };
    foreach(string volhdd in mi.Disk_Values) {
      Hdd_va.Items.Add(string.Format("Обьем : {0}", volhdd));

    }
    Disk.Items.Add(Hdd_va);
  }


  ceo.Items.Add(Disk);
  treeView.Items.Add(ceo);
  Disk.IsExpanded = true;


}
}
```

При этом если у меня в системе несколько дисков, то в каждом дочерней ветке у меня идет дубляж места , что и понятно так как цикл ...

Как бы мне очищать дубляж? 
[image: Вывод]

**Обновление**

```
treeView.Items.Add(sdf);
foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
{

 TreeViewItem Hdd_va = new TreeViewItem()
  {
        Header = "HDD: " + mo["caption"]
  };
   Hdd_va.Items.Add(string.Format("FreeSpace : {0}", mo["Size"]));


    sdf.Items.Add(Hdd_va);
}
```

Comment: Ну так, вы же сами делаете неправильно. Зачем вам вложенный цикл? Получайте список дисков как объектов, у каждого объекта запрашивайте имя и объём.

Comment: так вот вопрос, я не могу понять как запросить у каждого объекта полученного имя.